# Flutter Dio HTTPS Certificate Validation Ignoring onBadCertificate - CA Cert Problem?

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl-certificate, http2, dio

I've run into a bit of a quandary. I'm writing a client/server application. The frontend is in Flutter and uses the Dio http package, the backend is Java. The backend REST API is secured via TLS certificate.

As many other questions have pointed out, Flutter doesn't seem to have access to the system CA Certificate store on all platforms. This is problematic because I intend to allow for self hosting of the server application, meaning certificates from all different CAs could be utilized server-side, so my HTTP client will need to support all of the CAs that a typical web browser supports.

Dio apparently allows you to set a trusted cert chain, but I'm wondering how best to leverage that.

Has anyone encountered this problem before. What solution did you implement to fix this?

These are the solutions I've thought of so far:

1. Allow user to "upload" ca cert bundle and store bytes in shared_preferences (difficult for users)
2. Find another way to validate the certificate e.g. with user entered thumbprint? (less difficult, let all certs fail original validation, then do custom validatation with onBadCertificate against stored thumbprint)
3. Find a package which offers access to system certificate store
4. Ship inside the application a majority of big name CA certs and trust them with Dio somehow

The other issue I came here about is that Dio appears to be ignoring my onBadCertificate method. I declared this inside a ConnectionManager, should I not do that?

Here is the code that is being ignored:

```dart
var dio = Dio()
  ..options.baseUrl = server
  ..interceptors.add(LogInterceptor())
  ..interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar))
  ..httpClientAdapter = Http2Adapter(
    ConnectionManager(
      idleTimeout: 10000,
      // Ignore bad certificate
      onClientCreate: (_, config) => {
        //config.context?.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(File("/assets/certs/wildcard.pem").readAsBytesSync()),
        config.onBadCertificate = (_) => true, // <-- ignored, should bypass check
      }
    ),
  );
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, Flutter was in fact capable of using the system CA Certificate store. As I test other platforms, I'll update if I run into any problems with certificates. But this one is solved!

Comment: "Flutter doesn't seem to have access to the system CA Certificate store on all platforms" maybe correct but on these platforms, Flutter does come with its own truststore which contains more or less the same amount of CA as Mozilla. So, are you sure you do actually have a problem? Do you know a CA which is not supported which should be supported by Flutter?

Comment: I am using an Entrust certificate, purchased directly from Entrust. Dio couldn't validate the certificate on Android but it worked fine on Windows.

Comment: What version of Android? Is the CA in the phones truststore?

Comment: @julemand101 Pixel 4 API 30. Let me check. I'm using the emulator so it could be that the emulator just doesn't have a fully configured truststore.

Comment: Alternative, it could be a lot of other issues. E.g. if your server does not send the intermediate certificates. Some browsers ignores this problem if they can guess the root certificate based on historic data about the intermediate certificates. So badly configured servers can stay hidden.

Comment: @julemand101 the emulator does have all of the Entrust CA certs that the Windows platform does. I will update the server JKS file with the full certificate chain and see if that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240582/discussion-between-julemand101-and-thefunk).

Comment: So, what is the status of this problem? Did you find a solution or do you still need some help to find the core issue? :)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your suggestion of using the fullchain on the server, I never had a chance to check it until now. With the fullchain in place, Dio no longer complains about the certificate on the emulator and the connection is made successfully over HTTP2 from the Android emulator. If you'd like to submit your response as the answer, I'll confirm it.

Comment: Added an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue ended up being that the server did not provide the full certificate chain but only the leaf certificate. Some browsers hides this kinds of issues if the browser have seen the intermediate certificate somewhere else. So just because things works in the browser, it does not means the server is actually providing enough information for other TLS clients to verify the certificate chain.

The solution was therefore to configure the server to provide the full certificate chain.

Answer (score 4):

I am also have same issue, because on some old models of phones, users see Certificate error. So, I found this solution:

```
_dio = Dio(_baseOptions);

    //check bad certificate
    (_dio!.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = (HttpClient client) {
      client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
      return client;
    };
```

https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/32#issuecomment-487401443

Answer (score 1):

**Actual on March 2024:**

<s>`onHttpClientCreate`</s> callback is deprecated. Now you should use `createHttpClient` and return your own [`HttpClient`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) instance:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio/io.dart';

Dio createDio({required String baseUrl, bool trustSelfSigned = false}) {
  // initialize dio
  final dio = Dio()
    ..options.baseUrl = baseUrl;

  // allow self-signed certificate
  (dio.httpClientAdapter as IOHttpClientAdapter).createHttpClient = () {
    final client = HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => trustSelfSigned;
    return client;
  };
  
  return dio;
}
```